# Redirecting URL in IIS with querystring

Tags: c#, iis, query-string, redirect

I want to redirect my existing URL's to new URL For Example:

The input URL is:

```
www.mysite.com/show/fir/file/xyz.pdf
```

The outupt URL should be:

```
www.mysite.com/show.aspx?URL=show/fir/file/xyz.pdf
```

Comment: How's that going for you? Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0):

This is called Url Rewriting, preprocessing logic in Asp.Net is implemented by Http Handlers(based on extenstions) and Http Modules(based on methods).

You should refer [Url Rewriting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx) and [Http Handler and Http Modules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx).